# what's the type for `info` in the onclick callback in chrome.contextMenus.create?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using TypeScript to build a chrome extension, and in my background.js file (which as the name may imply is one of my background scripts) I am creating a new `contextMenu`, using the `chrome.contextMenus.create`. This method takes an optional onClick paramter in input where one of the arguments is `info` (docs can be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/#create)). Is anyone able to tell me where I can find more information on the type / structure of this `info` arg? I'm fairly sure it depends on the `contextType` for the context menu but can't seem to find anything usefule here.

Answer (score 1):

Always great when you find the answer a few minutes after posting the question...

For reference, for event pages, adding the `onClick` parameter in the create method isn't supported, and instead you have to add a listener like

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClick.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    ...
})
```

In this case, the `info` argument has the type `chrome.contextMenus.OnClickData`.

As an FYI, you can add the type definitions for the chrome API if you're using `npm` with

```
npm install --save-dev @types/chrome
```